# Set AttributesObject dynamically

Tags: code-behind, ext.net, treepanel

If I set this for a treepanel item:

```
nodeItem.AttributesObject = new { c0 = 11111, c222 = 100000, c444 = 200000 };
```

everything is OK, but I need to set AttributesObject dynamically. I mean the columns are dynamic so I don't know the property names in compile time.

when I use this:

```
var propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
.....
nodeItem.AttributesObject = propertyValues;
```

It doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Reflection to create an object with dynamic properties.

Or use a Node's CustomAttributes.

```
Ext.Net.Node node = new Ext.Net.Node();

node.CustomAttributes.Add(new ConfigItem("c0", "11111", ParameterMode.Raw));
node.CustomAttributes.Add(new ConfigItem("c222", "100000", ParameterMode.Raw));
```